# Cannot read properties of undefined using split in browser.umd.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, string, vercel

Hello Im getting error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split').
When I see it in the console [image]

If I click the link to the error it shows me the browser.umd.js file with this line:
[image]

any one knows whats the problem?

code:

```
const verifyJwt = (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('entered middle');
    let name = 'token=';
    const header = req.headers['cookie'];
    const token = header && header.split('=')[1];
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send({msg: "Login first please!"})
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if(err) return res.status(403).send({msg:"Not authoraized"})
      next();
    });
}

module.exports = verifyJwt
```

Comment: t.versions.node is  getting undefined value

Comment: what does it mean? what is t? i dont declare it or use it anywhere

Comment: @AmitHadad please share the code piece where you are using the split function in your project

Comment: where you have used async await ? when compiling  const token = header && header.split('=')[1];  header has no value . make it  await function

Comment: thats a middleware, so only when I go to certain api it calls it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because of an other error that was found in the code but havent notice, because of this the string was undefined value and does not have the func split.